# Tkinter ScrolledText widget not appearing

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-scrolledtext

I'm trying to add the ScrolledText widget to a Tkinter window. The program reads it perfectly as in it accepts the INSERT method for it with no errors but it's not showing up. The problem came up when I added Notebook Tabs. I've attached the code snippet. I used the place() method because I need the rest of my buttons and labels arranged in a specific pattern.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import datetime

# Variables
window = Tk()
window.title("Vesnica Pomenire")
window.geometry('1500x1000')
var = IntVar()
var.set(1)

txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window,width=40,height=10)
txt.place(x=50, y=50)
```

Comment: did You know that You can do this?: `from tkinter import scrolledtext, messagebox, ttk` also what is the point of importing tkinter and then importing everything from tkinter?

Comment: Please make your question more understandable. When I run the program, I see the scroll box.

Comment: When I add the missing call to `mainloop` I see the scrolledtext widget.

Comment: @Matiiss: when you do `from tkinter import *`, those other modules don't get imported. They have to be imported separately.

Comment: @BryanOakley that I already tested so I deleted that comment but still OP could import like this: `from tkinter import scrolledtext, messagebox, ttk` (this as far as I know should work) and that would save some space

Comment: Try changing `place()` with `pack()`.

Comment: Your code works fine after adding `window.mainloop()`.  *"The problem came up when I added Notebook Tabs"*, there is nothing related to a notebook tab.  Better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `mainloop()`

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import scrolledtext
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import os
import datetime

# Variables
window = Tk()
window.title("Vesnica Pomenire")
window.geometry('1500x1000')
var = IntVar()
var.set(1)

txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window,width=40,height=10)
txt.place(x=50, y=50)

window.mainloop() #You are missing this
```

You can read more about `mainloop()` [here](https://www.educba.com/tkinter-mainloop/)

Answer (score 0):

You really missed mainloop command

```
window.mainloop()
```

add this at the bottom of your code and it will do the thing